# How to access the column name which contains dot . in select query

Tags: mysql, database

I have tried backticks `` aswell .

My Column name is complaintlgeo.lat while writing the query as

```
 select `complaintlgeo.lat` from mandapet.pgr_view
```

I'm getting the following Errors

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "complaintlgeo" LINE 1:
>   select `complaintlgeo.lat` from mandapet.pgr_view
>             ^
> ```
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "complaintlgeo" SQL state:
>   42P01 Character: 9

Comment: @Siguza   .the link in your comment refer to sql-server   not to mysql

Comment: where/how are you using this query? as written it SHOULD work.

Comment: im trying this query with postgresql  query tool

Comment: And im calling this data from a View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try with [] ?

```
select [complaintlgeo].[lat] from mandapet.pgr_view
```

or

```
select [complaintlgeo.lat] from mandapet.pgr_view
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply cosmo .yeah i have tried that as well